# How to use third party package in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4 and I want to use a third party package within this framework. I did this to install it:

1) Add package name to composer.json file

2) Run `composer update` command

Now I have package available in /vendors folder. My question is, how to use it inside the Laravel now?

Looking in the config/app.php file, I can not add it to "providers" array as far as I can see, nor "aliases".

When I try to instantiate that package class directly in controller I get the error "Class not found" ( I tried full name to the class: `$pack = new /vendor/package.../class.php` )

Any help on how to include and use the class in the laravel greatly appreciated

Comment: Will help to help you if you give us the package url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the package provides a ServiceProvider, add it to `app/config/app.php`.

Otherwise composer has already took care of autoloading for you, so you just have to:

```
$package = new Package;
```

In the cases where the package is namespaced, you'll have to:

```
$package = new PackageNamespace\Package;
```

To be sure, take a look at the `vendor/composer/autoload_*` files, usually `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`, search for the package name or class name and you'll see how it is named. Or just take a look at the main package souce file, usually in:

```
vendor/vendorName/packageName/[src or lib or whatever]/Package.php
```

EDIT

I just installed it here and did:

```
Route::get('test', function()
{
    dd(new WideImage\WideImage);
});
```

Works like a charm. This package is in the 'namespaced' case I wrote above.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply Antonio, I just tried this but somehow it's still not recognizing class. I'm trying this using wideimage  https://packagist.org/packages/smottt/wideimage , I checked file you mentioned and yes it's loaded in composer/autoload_classmap.php. Name seems to be WideImage. I tried `new WideImage` but doesn't work